# Exporting Android Library project with resource folder images

Tags: android, resources, executable-jar

I am new to Android. I am using the reusable code, so I convert that to JAR file. I am using images from JAR source res folder. I have accessed those images by "**R.drawable.imagename**" in library source. While I am converting the library source to JAR, I have export those res folder. If I am using the JAR in another **android application, that will be crashed**. I have followed the link below to convert  the library source to JAR.

"http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm".

Where I am doing things wrong.? Is there any another **procedure to convert the android library project to JAR with resources**.? or Is there any wrong in **accessing the res folder image in android library source**.?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

The new Gradle based build system supports ["aar" files](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format) which , apart from compiled code, can contain resources etc as well.

**OLD:**

Resource packaging in library projects is not supported by android build tools. You will have to provide a separate `zip` for `res` folder along with the `jar` file.

Code goes in `jar` (for library) or `dex` (for app). Resources are separately bundled into `apk` file. Hence the SDK resource packager tool works only when you are exporting an `apk` file.

Yes, a `jar` file can contain resources, but, dependent android project's won't look up in `jar` file for resources.

Comment: But in this link "http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#considerations" under "Library projects cannot include raw assets" this topic, we can found res/ folder is supported in JAR.

Comment: Oh. There is no procedure for exporting res folder along with the JAR. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi,Is there any link deals with unable to exporting JAR with res folder.? I am tired of googling. If you know please help me.

Comment: @Karthick You can package resource and make a `jar` file, that's possible. **But** android project structure _demands_ that resources _to be in its `res`_ folder **only**. Hence, resources packaged in that `jar` are useless.

Comment: Yes, If I am place the images which are same name and resolution as in the library source in the target android application, it seems working fine.

Comment: I have exported jar with resources in assets folder using ant. Now . I want these resources to be a part of .dex
Any idea how to implement this ?